# Remove all characters at the beginning of string up to certain character in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an address field in which I only want to extract only the city and the state.  The data is stored as such: (1234 Cherry ST_Sometown_ST).  I would like to removed everything up to and including the first underscore.  Is there an easy way to do this with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` or another similar function?

The only think I have found so far is the ability to remove an Nth number.

Comment: try regexp_instr. This will locate the _ for you, use substring functions to select just the info up to that character location.  Oracle.com link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62a0a/1)**

```
select substr(address, instr(address, '_') + 1, length(address)) as "CityState"
from address
```